# Is it possible to configure api permission to Azure Active Directory app using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I have manually registered App in Azure Active Directory.
To this App, I need to configure Microsoft Graph, Azure Key vault API's and set permissions to that.

Is it possible to configure API's and set permission to AAD app using ARM template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible using ARM Template

Comment: Yeah, because Azure AD is above subscriptions.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same using powershell ?

Comment: probably yes, but thats another question :)

Comment: ok ,l will add it as another question , let me know if you have any info on how to achieve it using powershell